# An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'numbe

Tags: typescript

Why the following interface

```
export interface Interface<T> {
    [id:number | string]: T[]
}
```

Throw the error

> An index signature parameter type must be 'string' or 'numbe

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried separating each out?

```js
export interface Interface<T> {
  [id: string]: T[];
  [id: number]: T[];
}

// And then using it...
const nums: Interface<number> = {
  one: [1, 2],
  2: [2, 3]
};
```